# Paypal checkout with coupon applied returns wrong grand total

Tags: paypal

Have to fix this bug: magento works properly with prices and vat and coupon also, but when you place and order, using a coupon, and choose to pay with paypal it collects a wrong amount. usually less. Looks like if paypal re-calculate the goods price, the vat, and applies the coupon by itself not just taking from magento the grand total --it is not strange, what I cannot fix is that the two grand total are DIFFERENT. the mangetos is correct the paypal's is wrong (lower). As a result I have a suspected fraud, cause the amount collected is less than the magento's grand total. WHERE should I look to fix it ? THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/222075/P60/

In Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment::_isCaptureFinal()

Commented the line and added a precision fix. In your case the precision would be greater or just use an arbitrary number without opening a door to bad validation/vulnerability.

```
//if ($orderGrandTotal == $this->_formatAmount($this->getBaseAmountPaid(), true) + $amountToCapture) {
if (abs($orderGrandTotal - ($this->_formatAmount($this->getBaseAmountPaid(), true) + $amountToCapture)) <= 0.1 ) {
```

They are doing something with the forum right now. I'd suggest to read the topic quickly if it is of any help :)

If this is also a precision issue of total calculation you can try to modify:
Mage_Core_Model_Store::roundPrice()

```
// return round($price, 2); to
return round($price, 4);
```

and test everything regarding totals.